# LEFT JOIN is not working for 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Basically I have 2 tables

- Topics
- Users

I am trying to use a left join so that I can link the "posted_by" in "topics" with "user_id" in "users", so that I can output both the users.username for display, as well as users.profile(avatar picture).

Here is my current code, which is giving me boolean errors.

```
        <?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';

    $sql = " SELECT *, users.id, users.username, users.profile
        FROM `topics` 
        LEFT JOIN
        users ON topics.posted_by = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topic_id']) . " users.user_id ORDER BY `posted` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Start looping table row
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <table>
      <tr> 
        <td rowspan="4"> Avatar code to go here<br>
           <? echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $rows['category']; ?> > <? echo $rows['sub_category']; ?> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><? echo $rows['posted']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><? echo $rows['topic_data']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="view_topic.php?id=<? echo $rows['topic_id']; ?>">Reply</a> (<? echo $rows['reply']; ?>) Replies</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
    // Exit looping and close connection 
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the actual error message. Though I'm going to guess that your query is failing - try adding in a call to `mysql_error` to see what your database is actually returning.

Comment: Your query is wrong. This question would be better if you removed all the HTML code, showed us your errors and focused on fixed the query

Comment: The error I am getting is 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home3/site/public_html/topics.php on line 15

Line 15 is while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using something like

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id,     topics.category, topics.sub_category, 
topics.topic_data, topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
FROM users WHERE topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";
```

Try adding

$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, 
topics.topic_data, topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
 FROM **users, topics** WHERE topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";

Comment: That did it! was missing the 2nd table after FROM >_<

Answer (score 0):

`ON topics.posted_by = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topic_id']) . " users.user_id` you know this will produce `ON topics.posted_by = 1 users.user_id` for example which is invalid SQL syntax. Use WHERE instead

`ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id WHERE topics.id = (topic_id_variable)`

P.S.: Using `mysql_` is highly not recommended. You should change the API.

Comment: $sql = " SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
    topics.posted_by, topics.posted, users.id, users.username, users.profile
    FROM `topics` 
    LEFT JOIN
    users WHERE topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY `posted` DESC";

Is that better?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. After using `JOIN` you have to provide `ON` or `USING` then in WHERE clause filter by topics.id.

Comment: `SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, topics.posted_by, topics.posted, users.id, users.username, users.profile FROM topics LEFT JOIN users ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY posted DESC`

or

 `SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, topics.posted_by, topics.posted, users.id, users.username, users.profile FROM topics LEFT JOIN users ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id WHERE topics.id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topic_id']) . "' ORDER BY posted DESC`

Comment: I think I was confusing myself, how about

$sql = " SELECT *, users.id, users.username, users.profile
        FROM `topics` 
        LEFT JOIN
        `users` WHERE topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY `posted` DESC";

???

Comment: I just tried both of you examples @royal bg, neither worked, still getting the boolean error message :(

Comment: echo the $sql and post it here

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide how `users` relates to `topics` in your join clause. You have provided a outside variable to your join clause. This doesn't allow the database engine to establish a relationship on how the two tables should be joined.

I believe the query you are expecting should be something like this

```
$sql = " SELECT *, users.id, users.username, users.profile
        FROM `topics` 
        LEFT JOIN
        users ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id 
        WHERE topics.id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['topic_id']) . "'
        ORDER BY `posted` DESC";
```

Comment: I thought I had?

$sql = " SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
    topics.posted_by, topics.posted, users.id, users.username, users.profile
    FROM `topics` 
    LEFT JOIN
    users WHERE topics.posted_by = users.user_id ORDER BY `posted` DESC";

posted_by(is an init) is linked to user_id. Am I doing it wrong?